# How to send email from a form to my gmail using pear package

Tags: php, smtp

I have been struggling with the code below to send email to my gmail from a form. But I give up.  See the code below:

```
                            require_once('../php/Mail.php');
                            require_once('../php/Mail/RFC822.php');
                            //function to send email
                            function send_email($to,$from,$subject,$body,$is_body_html=false) {
                                if(! valid_email($to))
                                {
                                    throw new Exception('This email address in invalid: '.htmlspecialchars($to));
                                }
                                if(! valid_email($from))
                                {
                                    throw new Exception('This email address in invalid: '.htmlspecialchars($from));
                                }
                                //set up an array which can hold the SMTP server detail
                                $smtp=array();
                                $smtp['host']='ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
                                $smtp['port']=465;
                                $smtp['auth']=true;
                                $smtp['username']='my_username@gmail.com';
                                $smtp['password']='my_pass';

                                //create the mailer object using which can connect to your SMTP server
                                $mailer=Mail::factory('smtp',$smtp);
                                //check the returned value when creating the mailer object
                                if(PEAR::isError($mailer))
                                    {
                                    throw new Exception('Could not create the mailer object.');
                                    }
                                //as the send method of the mailer object accepts the reciepients and headers as an array, create 
                                //and set up the arrays

                                $recipients=array();
                                $recipients['to']=$to;

                                $headers=array();
                                $headers['from']=$from;
                                $headers['to']=$to;
                                $headers['subject']=$subject;
                                //check if the content is set to be html
                                if($is_body_html)
                                    {
                                    $headers['Content-type']='text/html';
                                    }
                               //send the email
                               $result=$mailer->send($recipients,$headers,$body);
                               //check the returned value when sending the email
                                if(PEAR::isError($result))
                                    {
                                    throw new Exception('There was an error while trying to send the email: '.htmlspecialchars($result));
                                    }
                            } //end of send_email function
```

The error message I got is  as below

> Error: exception 'Exception' with message 'There was an error while trying to send the email: Failed to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 [SMTP: Failed to connect socket: Connection timed out (code: -1, response: )]' in /home/biwucr/public_html/functions/mailer_function.php:49 Stack trace: #0 /home/biwucr/public_html/send-quote.php(62): send_email('yibeltalisme@gm...', 'Yibeltal sour...', false) #1 {main}

I can't understand why.

Do I have to contact my host company?

Comment: The problem is with connection to GMAIL's SMTP server... Are Your settings correct?

Comment: can you tell me any configuration I have to make on the GMAIL SMTP?

Answer (score 1):

The Gmail's SMTP server address is **SMTP.GOOGLEMAIL.COM** not SMTP.GMAIL.COM.

Therefore Your settings should be:

```
// ...
$smtp=array();
$smtp['host']='ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you but I tried with ssl://smtp.googlemail.com and no change.

Comment: And is Your **username** and **password** correct for Your SMTP?

Comment: Thank you shadyyx, But I am sure about the Password and Username. I am expecting something. Should I have to install ssl sertificate on the server? My host asked me to purchase ssl certificate when I purchase the host service and I didn't do that. could it be the reason?

Comment: Nope. The SSL is just needed on GOOGLE's server and You are just connecting to it, so there is no need to install SSL certificate on Your host. If You are sure that SMTP settings are correct maybe there is another problem within Your webhosting - maybe a communication to some external ports (like SSL's 465 port) is blocked by Your webhosting server's firewall...

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try uncommenting out this line from your php.ini file:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```